# jquery ajax call returning an error with readystate 4, status 200, statustext ok

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is really boggling my mind. I get an error callback from ajax. But if I take the res.responseText (which comes back correct, btw) from the error message and use it, it does the right thing. Just as if I had received a success callback.

The data is set like this:

```
var dataToSend = {fieldname : textdata};
```

and the ajax call is like this:

```
var ajaxOptions = {
    url: '/newpage',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(res) {
        console.log("success!");
        $('#' + divname).html(res);
    },
    error: function(res) {
        console.log("There was an error: " + JSON.stringify(res));
        $('#' + divname).html(res.responseText);
    }
};

$.ajax(ajaxOptions);
```

The error message is : There was an error: `{"readyState":4,"responseText" [this part is perfectly fine], "status":200, "statusText":"OK"}`.

Comment: `dataType: 'json',` this is expected response from the source. can you make sure the source you are hitting is producing json as outcome? if not try after removing it.

Comment: looks like you are returning text/html ....so error is likely a json parse error. Remove `dataType:'json'`. Show what is actually returned

Comment: @Jai -- That was a good guess! I changed the type to JSON data in my database, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @lynvie see json should have to be like `{key:value}` or `[{k:v},{k:v}...n]` can you make sure you are producing this when you hit it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If your responseText isn't a correct JSON, a parsing error is thrown. Either **make sure your response is a valid JSON** or **remove `dataType: "json"`**.

From [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> **dataType** (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>
> Type: String
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none
>   is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of
>   the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield
>   a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and
>   anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and
>   the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are:

...

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript
>   object. Cross-domain "json" requests are converted to "jsonp" unless
>   the request includes jsonp: false in its request options. The JSON
>   data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and
>   a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also
>   rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead.
>   (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

Answer (score 2):

This happens to be when you have `dataType` set to get the response but the response is not what you set in the datatype.

So in your case `dataType: 'json',` is set and as you mentioned at the comment section you have set `string` at the backend, so you need to change your datatype to `text`.

change your datatype to:

```
dataType: 'text',
```

Comment: I am using mongodb. I have { type: Schema.Types.Mixed}. When I console.log the var dataToSend it prints : "title":"This title.". I then send it with JSON.stringify(dataToSend). Is this not enough for it to be JSON data?

Comment: @lynvie, the problem you are having is with the respon's data, not with the sent data. You must do `console.log(responseText)` and check if that is a JSON

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem serverside is to echo an empty array, json encoded:

```
echo json_encode([]);
return;
```

Then the success function gets triggered instead of the error.

Or just change scriptside `dataType: 'json',` to `dataType: 'text',` to tell jquery to receive a text response.