# Ajax get shopping cart on page load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to load the shopping cart whenever the page is loaded but nothing happens. The console log is not telling me anything either. I have a post to cart system that works fine, so I cant figure out why this doesnt work.
I am using Laravel with a shopping cart plugin.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '{{route("getCart")}}',
    error: function(data) {
      var errors = data.responseJSON;
      console.log(errors);
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#cartResult').html(data.cartCount)
    },
  });
});
```

```php
public function cartGet() 
{
  $cartCount = Cart::content() - > count();
  $data = array('cartCount' => $cartCount);
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: console does not write anything success method is falling, you can add to success method alert(JSON.stringify(data)); for see what you are returning

Comment: I only get this message @tdayi.

{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

Comment: Are you sure the address is correct? url: '{{route("getCart")}}'

Comment: Yes I am certain

Comment: Do you try to write a log in the cartGet() method?

Comment: I have. I treid writing: console.log(data.cartCount); and console.log(data);

None of them works. The console tells me that data is undefined.

Comment: Your console.log() statement is inside the success function, right? Just checking

Comment: Yes, I tested with all alternatives. The function succeeds but does not return any actual data. It seems that it is unable to define data but the function still runs through as successful.

Comment: @Zcylon will you look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637677/jquery-ajax-call-returning-an-error-with-readystate-4-status-200-statustext-ok/32637956

Answer (score 0):

Try `return json_encode($data);` instead of `echo`.

You can also avoid `json_encode` and just use `return $data;`.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not make any difference. Also echo works with my post form @nakov.

Comment: it does if you open the link in a browser tab, won't work in ajax, because you are not returning the data. 
Do you have your JS code in a blade view, or? Make sure that your ready function is called at all.

Comment: It is in a blade view yes, should I place it in a seprate js file?

Comment: it is fine, try `console.log` as a first line in your ready function just to make sure that the script is executed.

Comment: I see above another comment from you. So if that's what it returns, it is because you use `echo` instead of return. Remove `dataType: 'json'` from the ajax. And also return the data instead of echoing.

Comment: I have tested and it is executing.

Comment: It is now returning. I know that the function is successful with console.log testing, but it does not update any field or actually pass any data

Comment: Based on the code if you have the element with id cartResult everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simply return $data, laravel will place the correct header in response.
if you return json_endode($data) a Content-type: text/plain header will be placed, 
if you return $data (which is a structure) laravel will json_encode under the hood and place a Content-type: application/json header.
your code should look like this:

```
public function cartGet() 
{
  return ['cartCount' => Cart::content()->count()];
}
```

Comment: Im not entirely sure what you mean here. Laravel will automatically understand what ''data'' means? 
I tried your code, it did not make any difference :/ @simonecosci

Comment: yes it does.
as you can see [here](https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/master/Response.php) the setContent method morphs the response to json in case of Arrayable, Jsonable, ArrayObject or JsonSerializable (or is_array) $content

Answer (score 0):

It might be because in your $.ajax call you've set `dataType: 'json'`

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> As of jQuery 1.5, jQuery can convert a dataType from what it received
>   in the Content-Type header to what you require. For example, if you
>   want a text response to be treated as XML, use "text xml" for the
>   dataType. You can also make a JSONP request, have it received as text,
>   and interpreted by jQuery as XML: "jsonp text xml". Similarly, a
>   shorthand string such as "jsonp xml" will first attempt to convert
>   from jsonp to xml, and, failing that, convert from jsonp to text, and
>   then from text to xml.

When you `echo json_encode()`, it sends the data straight to the php output stream buffer and Laravel doesn't know that it needs to add a `Content-Type: application/json` header to its response. Without it, maybe jQuery needs the dataType to be "text json"?

As others have mentioned, you can `return $data` from your controller. Laravel will automatically cast your array to json, and it will also set the appropriate Content-Type headers. Maybe try that first?

Comment: Thank you. 
I have tried returning the data. It appears my console says that data is undefined regardless of what I do. 

The odd thing is also that echo json_encode($data) works with the post to cart code. @Travis Britz