# JSON response doesn't match AJAX

Tags: json, ajax

I have the same issue but my data are in json, the issue is not fixed : [jquery ajax call returning an error with readystate 4, status 200, statustext ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637677/jquery-ajax-call-returning-an-error-with-readystate-4-status-200-statustext-ok)

My coworker doesn't have the same issue but we have the same code.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost/");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
```

I return this reponse to my front with ajax

```
echo json_encode(array(
                    'code' => 200,
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'message' => "Account is already activated",
                ));
```

but I have this in my debug console :

```
{
  "readyState": 4,
  "responseText": "1{\"code\":200,\"status\":\"error\",\"message\":\"Account is already activated\"}",
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK"
}
```

If I change json to text the "1" persist but I haven't got an another echo in my code :/

Answer (score 0):

I put a echo '1' in my databasemanager file to connect to my database. So it's normal.